# How to install kernel module for android?

Tags: custom-roms, installation, kernel, android-sdk, command-line

I currently have a custom kernel and ROM installed on my android device. The kernel I'm using comes with a separate download with kernel modules that you are to install yourself if you want. However no instructions are given on how to do it, also I cannot find any tutorial on-line how to do it.

So I have a bunch of `.ko` files, Android SDK and my rooted android device. How do I install these kernel modules?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `adb` to push them to `/system/lib/modules`, then reboot. Android should load them at boot as long as they're in that directory, I believe.

```
shell> adb push module.ko /system/lib/modules/
shell> adb reboot
```

If you get a "read-only filesystem" error then remount `/system` as read/write first, then push them. Usually you can do this with `adb remount`. You could probably also put them onto an SD card and then use a file manager to copy them over if you want.

You can also use `insmod` to manually load a module into the kernel at runtime, but it wouldn't be reloaded if you reboot. This would allow you to skip the initial reboot, though, since you should be able to `insmod` all of the modules after you push them onto the device.

Comment: I don't have the folder `/system/lib/modules/` is it ok to create it or does that mean the modules might be loaded elsewhere?

Comment: I've tried creating the folder modules and putting a module in there and rebooted and the module hasn't loaded. The module only seems to work if I insmod it.

Comment: @Brady: Hm, haven't seen that one before. I suppose you could add a bunch of `insmod` statements to your `/init.rc`, though that's kind of ugly. What kind of device is this?

Comment: galaxy tab 10.1 16GB wifi. I don't mind editing `init.rc`. If I am though do I simply edit init.rc in a text editor and at the end add: `insmod /path/to/module.ko`?

Comment: @Brady: That should be all you need to do, as far as I know. [Here's a mailing list reference](http://osdir.com/ml/android-platform/2010-11/msg00207.html) where someone mentions it (he also apparently couldn't get it to work when the modules were in `/etc` for some reason, but he says `/lib/modules` was fine).

Comment: ok modules are now in `/lib/modules/` I edit my `init.rc` and at the end use the insmod command. It saves ok but when I reboot the modules have not loaded and the changes to the init.rc are gone...

Comment: also since reboot the modules have disappeared from /lib/modules

Comment: @Brady: That sounds almost like you're NAND locked, though I'm not sure how you would have a custom ROM/kernel if you were. You could try putting them in `/data/local` or on your sdcard, perhaps, and `insmod`ing them from there, but you'd have to do it manually (or maybe use [gScript](https://market.android.com/details?id=nl.rogro.GScriptLite&feature=more_from_developer) or something) if the `init.rc` changes aren't sticking...

Comment: Thanks for all your help on this. I will look up about gscript. If I get stuck I'll start a new question.

Comment: One of my devices have them in `/system/vendor/modules/` directory.